# I'm going to have to ask you again to

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

A man has left his seat and been told to go back to it, which he has done. The man has now left his seat again...

***Sir, I'm going to have to ask you again to go back to your seat.***

Is the sentence phrased in a perfectly natural way? Is the placement of "again" natural?

Answer (score 1):

> Sir, I'm going to have to ask you again to go back to your seat

Yes, this is correct. It means that the speaker is *asking* again.  From this sentence alone, we do not know whether the man returned to his seat in between the requests. All we know is that he has been asked more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Most native speakers in the US at least would see nothing wrong with your wording.

> Sir, I'm going to have to ask you again to go back to your seat.

But you ask if it is a "perfectly natural way". I feel the best wording would not include the works "going to have to". The fact they can be removed without changing the meaning suggests they are unnecessary.

Consider using:
***Sir, I'm asking you again to go back to your seat.***

Less is more.

Comment: I feel a British speaker would be likely to use "going to have to" to avoid conflict.  "I'm telling you because it is the rules not because I have anything personal dislike of you".  US English speaker do tend to be more direct.

Comment: I think James K’s comment is correct for US speakers as well.